# Редактирование раздела справки «Как выполнять поиск?»

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, правила, справка, поиск

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Описания операторов отформатированы по-разному.

Часть: **`оператор:параметры`**

> `user:mine` или `user:me` (или любой личный номер пользователя) выводит только ваши сообщения (или только сообщения того пользователя, чей личный номер вы ввели);

Другие: **`оператор:` параметры**

> `isaccepted:` yes/true/1 выводит только ответы, отмеченные как "принятые"; no/false/0 выводит только ответы которые не отмечены как принятые.

На двух форматирования вообще нет: **оператор: параметры**

> duplicate: yes/true/1 выводит вопросы, отмеченные как дубликат другого вопроса; no/false/0 исключает дублирующиеся вопросы из поиска.
>
> migrated: yes/true/1 выводит только вопросы, перенесенные на другой сайт; no/false/0 исключает перенесенные вопросы из поиска.

Считаю, что везде должен быть формат **`оператор:параметры`**. Могу сам исправить, если дадут исходники.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Редактирование раздела справки ["Как выполнять поиск?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching).

---

### Как выполнять поиск?

Для выполнения поиска введите ваш поисковый запрос в строку поиска в верхнем правом углу любой страницы и нажмите `Ввод`.

Если вы хотите уточнить или ограничить область поиска, воспользуйтесь следующими фильтрами.

- Для поиска по заданным меткам, дополните поисковый запрос меткой в квадратных скобках. Например, `[техобслуживание] место` – выполняет поиск слова "место" в сообщениях отмеченных меткой `[техобслуживание]`.
- Для поиска точной фразы или набора специальных символов, используйте кавычки. Например, `"спустившая шина"` или `"<%#"`.
- Для поиска в заголовках вопросов, используйте фильтр `title:`. Для поиска в теле сообщения (без заголовка) используйте фильтр `body:`.
- Для поиска в ваших сообщениях используйте фильтр `user:me`. Например, `user:me запрос` - выполняет поиск по слову "запрос" во всех ваших сообщениях.
- Чтобы исключить из результатов метку, термин или фразу, добавьте перед запрос символом `-`. Например, `кексы -единороги` - выполняет поиск сообщений, где упоминаются вкусные мучные десерты без волшебных существ, в то время как `[лорел] -[харди]` выполняет поиск только сообщений, относящиеся к первой половине классической пары комиков.
- Для поиска по шаблону, используйте подстановочный символ `*`. Например, `перем*` или `*мен`.

### Расширенный поиск

Сайт поддерживает набор расширенных операторов для поиска специфичной информации.

#### Диапазоны

Для поиска сообщений попадающих в заданный диапазон голосов, количества ответов или просмотров, можно использовать верхнюю или нижнюю границу или обе одновременно.

- `score:-1` или `score:-1..` - выполняет поиск сообщений с оценкой превышающей или равной -1.
- `views:500..1000` или `views:500-1000` - выполняет поиск вопросов с количеством просмотров от 500 до 1000.
- `answers:..3` - выполняет поиск вопросов содержащих 3 и менее ответов.

#### Даты

Для поиска сообщений соответствующих определенным датам или диапазону дат, используйте следующие фильтры.

- `created:` - для уточнения времени создания сообщения.
- `lastactive:` - для сообщений, активных в определенный период времени.

Формат задания дат.

- Абсолютные даты.

  - *Только год*. Например, `created:2012` - выполняет поиск сообщений, созданных с 1 января 2012 г. по 31 декабря 2012 г.;  `created:2012..2013` - выполняет поиск сообщений, созданных с 1 января 2012 г. по 31 декабря 2013 г.
  - *Год и месяц*. Например, `created:2012-04..2012-05` - выполняет поиск сообщений, созданных с 1 апреля 2012 г. по 31 мая 2012 г.
  - *Год, месяц и день*. Например, `lastactive:2012-04-03` - выполняет поиск сообщений, в которых была активность с 00:00 3 апреля 2012 г. по 23:59 3 апреля 2012 г.
- Относительные даты.

  - `1y`, `1m`, и `1d` – это сокращения для "последний год", " последний месяц" и "вчера". Например, если сегодня 15 апреля, то `created:1m` выполнит поиск сообщений, созданных с 1 по 31 марта. Используйте любое другое число вместо 1, чтобы просмотреть сообщения за любой другой интересующий вас промежуток времени.
  - Относительные даты в диапазоне `(1y..)` – выполняет поиск сообщений за равный промежуток времени в прошлом. Например, если требуется найти все активные сообщения за последние три месяца, используйте `lastactive:3m..` (таким образом, если сегодня 15 апреля, такой запрос выполняет поиск сообщений, которые были активны с 15 января до текущего момента). В дополнение, можно использовать диапазоны: `lastactive:3m..1m.`

**Обратите внимание**, что все время указано в формате UTC. В вашем временном поясе результаты могут отличаться.

#### Предпочтения участников

Вы можете ограничить область поиска по учётной записи пользователя (вашей или чьей-либо еще).

- `user:mine` или `user:me` (или `user:id_пользователя`) выполняет поиск только ваших сообщений (или того пользователя, чей `id` вы указали).
- `infavorites:mine` (или `user:id_пользователя`) выполняет поиск вопросов, которые вы (или пользователь, чей id вы указали) добавили в избранное.
- `intags:mine` выполняет поиск сообщений отмеченных метками, которые вы добавили в избранное (если у вас нет меток, поиск ничего не вернет, для улучшения результатов поиска обновите ваши настройки).

#### Логические операторы

Используйте `yes`/`no`, `true`/`false` или `1`/`0` (все пары действуют одинаково) как значения для следующих фильтров.

- `isaccepted:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск **ответов** отмеченных как принятые; `no`, `false` или `0` - выполняет поиск **ответов** не отмеченных как принятые.
- `hascode:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск сообщений содержащих блоки кода; `no`, `false` или `0` выполняет поиск сообщений не содержащих кода.
- `hasaccepted:`. `yes`, `true`, `1` - выполняет поиск **вопросов** имеющих ответы отмеченные как принятые; `no`, `false` или `0` - выполняет поиск **вопросов** не имеющих ответов отмеченных как принятые.
- `isanswered:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск **вопросов** содержащих как минимум [один ответ отмеченный как принятый или с положительной оценкой](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/); `no`, `false`, `0` - выполняет поиск **вопросов** без ответов отмеченных как принятый или ответов с положительной оценкой.
- `closed:`. `yes`, `true`, `1` - выполняет поиск закрытых вопросов; `no`, `false` или `0` - исключает из поиска закрытые вопросы.
- `duplicate:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск вопросов отмеченных как дубликаты; `no`, `false` или `0` - исключает из поиска вопросы отмеченные как дубликаты.
- `migrated:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск вопросов перенесенных на другой сайт; `no`, `false` или `0` - исключает из поиска перенесенные вопросы.
- `locked:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск заблокированных сообщений (с отключенными правками, голосами, комментариями и без возможности публикации новых ответов); `no`, `false` или `0` - выполняет поиск незаблокированных сообщений.
- `hasnotice:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск сообщений содержащих уведомления под ними; `no`, `false` или `0` выполняет поиск сообщений не содержащих прилагающихся уведомлений.
- `wiki:`. `yes`, `true` или `1` - выполняет поиск сообщений отмеченных как [общие](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts); `no`, `false` или `0` - выполняет поиск сообщений не отмеченных как общие.

#### Оператор `OR`

Для создания поискового запроса по нескольким меткам, разделите имена меток (заключенные в квадратные скобки) словом "or". Например, запрос `[widgets] or [geegaws]` - выполняет поиск вопросов отмеченных одной из этих меток.

#### Другие операторы

- `url:"example.com"` - выполняет поиск сообщений содержащих URL "example.com".
- `is:question`  - выполняет поиск только вопросов, `is:answer` - выполняет поиск только ответов.
- `inquestion:id` - выполняет поиск только в заданном вопросе. При выполнении поиска на странице какого-либо вопроса, можно использовать оператор `inquestion:this`, чтобы выполнить поиск в вопросе, который вы просматриваете в данный момент.

Comment: Похоже, форматирование вы уже исправили здесь? Предлагаете в этом же тексте делать дальнейшие правки?

Comment: Да, можно прямо этот же текст править.